# Display items of drop down based on each other

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

1) I have two drop downs with exactly the same values. I want the drop down 2 to display the values based on the selection of items of drop down 1. So the selected index of drop down 2 will be equal to or more than the selected index of drop down 1. ( this code is working)

but When I add one more drop down and based on its items the other two dropdowns should behave as:

2) If I select **TCD** in the first Dropdown and change to value B in the second dropdown the value should be B in the third dropdown too but If I select **BCD** from the first dropdown it should retain the values of other two dropdown from the previous selection.( should not go back to A)

The first part is working but the second part is having issues.

Fiddle : 1) http://jsfiddle.net/wtLm4805/2/

Fiddle with three dropdowns : 2) http://jsfiddle.net/wtLm4805/3/

```
 while (select2.firstChild) {
    select2.removeChild(select2.firstChild);
}

for (var i = 0; i < select1.options.length; i++) {
    var o = document.createElement("option");
    o.value = select1.options[i].value;
    o.text = select1.options[i].text;
    (i < select1.selectedIndex) 
? o.disabled = true 
: o.disabled = false ;        
    select2.appendChild(o);
}
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: missed function call `clickButton` instead of `clickButton()` in second fiddle

Comment: No after adding the call its not working as its supposed to.

Comment: yes, it shows script error. Please use onchange instead of onclick. Based on dropdown selected value you can use `$(this).val()` selected item to process the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one element with class `SELECTA` and one with class `SELECTB`, these will always be undefined:

```
var select1 = document.getElementsByClassName("SELECTA")[1];
var select2 = document.getElementsByClassName("SELECTB")[1];
var select1 = document.getElementsByClassName("SELECTA")[2];
var select2 = document.getElementsByClassName("SELECTB")[2];
```

If you're trying to target the options, you could move the classes to the options themselves, or you could reference them like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("SELECTA")[0].options[1]
```

Not sure why you're deleting/adding items to the `SELECTB` element, but is this what you're going for?

```js
function clickButton() {
  var Type= document.getElementById('Type');
  var select1= document.getElementById('SELECTA');
  var select2= document.getElementById('SELECTB');

  if(Type.value === 'TCD') {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < select1.options.length ; i++) {
      select2.options[i].disabled= i < select1.selectedIndex;
    }
    select2.value= select1.value;
  }
  else {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < select2.options.length ; i++) {
      select2.options[i].disabled= false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="Type" id="Type" onchange="clickButton()">
  <option value="TCD">TCD</option>
  <option value="MCD">MCD</option>
  <option value="BCD">BCD</option>
</select>

<select id="SELECTA" onchange="clickButton()">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<select id="SELECTB">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go somewhere along these lines

```js
var typeValue = 'TCD'; // default initialisation

$('#Type').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    if(value == 'TCD')
    {
        typeValue = 'TCD';
        // change something in other selects too
    }
    else if(value == 'MCD')
    {
        typeValue = 'MCD';
    }
    else if(value == 'BCD')
    {
        $('#SELECTA').val('B');
        $('#SELECTB').val('B');
        typeValue = 'BCD';
    }
    
});

$('#SELECTA').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    if(typeValue = 'TCD')
    {
        $('#SELECTB').val(value);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="Type" id="Type"  >
     <option value="TCD">TCD</option>
     <option value="MCD" >MCD</option>
     <option value="BCD" >BCD</option>
  </select>

<select id="SELECTA" class="SELECTA">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select id="SELECTB" class="SELECTB"  >
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```